# TypeError: list indices must be integers, not dict

Tags: python

My json file look likes this and I'm trying to access the element `syslog` in a for loop.

```
{
  "cleanup":{
    "folderpath":"/home/FBML7HR/logs",
    "logfilename":""
  },
  "preparation":{
    "configuration":{
      "src_configfile":"src.cfg",
      "dest_configfile":"/var/home/FBML7HR/etc/vxn.cfg"
    },
    "executable_info1":[
      {
        "login_info":{
          "hostname":"10.4.0.xxx",
          "username":"***",
          "password":"***"
        }
      },
      {
        "command":{
          "folderpath":"/var/home/FBML7HR/SrcCode/vxnservers/fdchost/north/test/hostsim/",
          "processname":"northhostsim",
          "parameters":"-d"
        }
      }
    ],
    "executable_info2":[
      {
        "login_info":{
          "hostname":"10.4.0.xxx",
          "username":"***",
          "password":"***"
        }
      },
      {
        "command":{
          "folderpath":"/var/home/FBML7HR/SrcCode/vxnservers/fdchost/north/build/Linux-2.6.18-194.8.1.el5/bin",
          "processname":"northhost",
          "parameters":"-s brazil -d"
        }
      }
    ],
    "executable_info3":[
      {
        "login_info":{
          "hostname":"10.4.0.xxx",
          "username":"***",
          "password":"***"
        }
      },
      {
        "command":{
          "folderpath":"cd /var/home/xxx/SrcCode/vxnservers/fdchost/north/test/vxnclient_mt",
          "processname":"vxnclient_north_mt",
          "parameters":"0 320 205 14897 16880 60000 60000 2 2"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "execution":[
    {
      "test_case":{
        "scriptname":"/var/home/FBML7HR/test/testcase1.sh",
        "testreport":{
          "syslog":"/var/log/messages",
          "backupsyslog":"backuplogs1.txt",
          "clientsimlog":"/var/home/FBML7HR/test/out.log",
          "backupclientsimlog":"Clientlogs1.txt"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "test_case":{
        "scriptname":"/var/home/FBML7HR/test/testcase2.sh",
        "testreport":{
          "syslog":"/var/log/messages",
          "backupsyslog":"backuplogs2.txt",
          "clientsimlog":"/var/home/FBML7HR/test/out.log",
          "backupclientsimlog":"Clientlogs2.txt"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "verification":{
    "testreport":{
      "syslog":"/var/log/messages",
      "backupsyslog":"backuplogs.txt",
      "reportfilename":"/var/home/FBML7HR/test/out.log",
      "backuplogfile":"Clientlogs.txt"
    }
  }
}
```

I do it like this:

```
for i in data['execution']:
    cmd = data['execution'][i]['test_case']['scriptname']
```

But I get the error saying "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not dict".
I'm new to python (and json as well). Could anybody suggest where I'm going wrong ?

Comment: Clearly `i` is a `dict`, so you can't use it to index into `data['execution']`. Shouldn't that just be `for i in data['execution']: cmd = i['test_case']['scriptname']`?

Comment: looks like `data` is a list, and not a dictionary. Are you sure this dictionary does not have an enclosing `[]` ?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You are looping over the *values* in the list referenced by `data['execution']`, *not* indices.

Just use those values (dictionaries) **directly**:

```
for i in data['execution']:
    cmd = i['test_case']['scriptname']
```

You probably want to give that a more meaningful loop name:

```
for entry in data['execution']:
    cmd = entry['test_case']['scriptname']
```

Answer (score 6):

- you can try this, it works for me

```
dataArray=data['execution']
for i in range(len(dataArray)):
    cmd = dataArray[i]['test_case']['scriptname']
```

- This exactly loops by indices, so there will not be any confusion,
- For me this is very simple and understandable