# Python Auction House Calculate Winner

Tags: python

```
print("Welcome to the Auction House")
name = input("Enter your name: ")
price = int(input("Enter your price: "))

total_list = []
def store_data(name, price):
    name_list = {}
    name_list["name"] = name
    name_list["price"] = price
    total_list.append(name_list)

def compare(highest_bid):
    winner = 0
    winn = ""
    for someone in highest_bid:
        if highest_bid[someone] > winner:
            winner = highest_bid["price"]
            winn = winner
    print(winn)

store_data(name, price)
something = True
while something:
    question = input("Is there other who want to bid? (y/n) ").lower()
    if question == "y":
        name = input("Enter your name: ")
        price = int(input("Enter your price: "))
        store_data(name, price)
    else:
        compare(total_list)
        something = False
```

Hello everyone, I'm building an auction action and having this error. if highest_bid[someone] > winner:

`TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict.`

I have tried several ways of doing it such as adding a list in compare(), etc but still couldn't solve the problem. I want to make it like who has the highest bid then who will win in the auction house but, of course, I would add some description after that but right now my problem is I couldn't determine who the winner using my compare(). I appreciate it if you can help out with my small little project.

Comment: your function `compare` expects a dictionary (you are trying to get the `"price"` item), but you are passing it `total_list` which is a list, so thus you get the error you see

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: list indices must be integers, not dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26266425/typeerror-list-indices-must-be-integers-not-dict)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed your code

```
def compare(highest_bid):
    winner = 0
    winn = ""
    for someone in highest_bid:
        if someone["price"] > winner:
            winner = someone["price"]
            winn = someone["name"]
    print(winn)
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem is at compare function.
here I fix it for you.

```
def compare(highest_bid):
    winner = 0
    winn = ""
    # for someone in highest_bid:
    #     if highest_bid[someone] > winner:
    #         winner = highest_bid["price"]
    #         winn = winner
    for someone in highest_bid:
        if someone["price"] > winner:
            winner = someone["price"]
            winn = winner
    print(winn)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access dictionary but total_list is a list. You can continuously update name_list as

```
name_list = {}
def store_data(name, price):
    name_list.update({name : price})
```

And then in compare function access the values using keys.

```
def compare(highest_bid):
    winner = 0
    winn = ""
    for someone in highest_bid:
        if highest_bid.get(someone) > winner:
            winner = highest_bid.get(someone)
            winn = winner
    print(winn)
```

Pass name_list in compare function.